ERROR: (gcloud.app.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The project must have a billing account attached
I am deploying a simple dashboard webapp in python. everything about the deployment is more or less identical to previous deployments, which have worked. (Same YAML, same authentication code, etc.)
However, when I deploy this next app, google cloud CLI throws the above error on gcloud app create.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The project must have a billing account attached
I've been unable to find a solution on various forums, besides "wait and try it later". Supposedly this works. But still curious as to why this error occurs / any more experienced advice.

have you perhaps used a restricted word in the projectID?

what is a restricted word? I'm new to Google Cloud

"everything about the deployment is more or less identical to previous deployments" - you're not that new! Some example restricted words are google, ssl, and null - I have no idea if there is a definitive list or not, perhaps google cloud platform documentation has them. I'm not saying this IS the issue though.

Yeh, I've had a bunch of apps that I've been waiting to deploy, and so doing it in bulk for the first time. Three apps worked fine but for some reason this isn't. - in any case I'll check on the restricted keywords, thank you !

ah, figured it out

Billing Accounts in Google Cloud Storage can only have a limited number of projects. In this case, it was 3.
So I just had to create a new Billing Account (can be the same card information).
